# Which data structure for query caching?

Tags: .net, caching, data-structures, collections

Iam looking for a suitable data structure for some kind of query caching for our .net web service that gets xml as query and returns xml as result.

The flow is as follows: The user gives a query string (~2kb in size) and gets a result (~50kb in size). The last n queries with their corresponding results are cached, so we need a O(1) lookup query->result. If the cache is full (cache_size=n) the oldest item should get removed from the cache.

So at the end I need a data structure that works mostly like a queue (enqueue and dequeue in O(1)) but also supports O(1) lookup for an item like a dictionary.

My first idea was to use a dictionary which maps from query to the result. For keeping track of the order of the items I would use a queue which also contains the queries. But the problem is then that I would waste memory and and will be slower to make all these lookups which the long query strings. I could use another dictionary which maps the queries to an created unique id value so the query strings are contained only in one collection.

Isn't there a simpler and more efficient solution for this imho simple task?

Comment: I don't think your solution would waste much memory (regarless of the size of the query strings), because the queue would only be holding a reference (32 bits) to the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple cache the [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class might do. For a bigger system you might want to consider a full blown caching solution like memcached.

Comment: Any idea if the ordered dictionary lets you update the order? If a cache hit occurs, it would be nice to be able to move the key to the "back of the queue".

Comment: I have just seen that this class is not generic. Why is there no generic version?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the existing `HttpContext.Cache` property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx

For a bigger/distributed system, look into memcached (or memcacheddotnet - http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/)

In terms of implementing it yourself, recommend you encapsulate an `OrderedDictionary<>` (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx) - the order of items added is preserved so you can access the first/last and add to the end.  Lookups for a fixed-size dictionary will be O(1) I believe.  Thing is it would be limited to a single AppDomain.

Comment: Thank you but, Iam looking for a solution which doesn't involve third party libraries

Comment: `HttpContext.Cache` is built-in to .NET and is designed specifically and exactly for your problem / question

Comment: From the view of my component I cannot access the HttpContext or any other web objects.

Comment: Do you definitely want the caching to be done at the component level?  Depending on what the component represents/models, it might be better always giving 'live' values and leaving the caching to the point in the process where it's needed for performance optimisation

Comment: There is a non-web-centric caching added in .NET 4.0 --  `System.Runtime.Caching`

Answer (score 1):

[System.Web.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx) supports a Cache class with time-based expiration and maximum bytes limit.  It needs .NET 4 though.

If you go bigger (and have access to something running Linux), I highly recommend [redis](http://redis.io).
I implemented a similar query cache using redis and it was a completely pain free process.